# there is Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Cannot find module '../formatMuiErrorMessage'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, vercel

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot find module '../formatMuiErrorMessage'
I haven't used '../formatMuiErrorMessage' anywhere in my code, Re-installed the node packages bu still this error is there

[image]

I installed npm uninstall @mui/base package and since that i am getting this error. i have unistalled this package but the error is still here. cleared cache, re-started the server but nothing works. what could be the solution?